# How do I get a list of items from a subset of a list, based on the items in another list in Java?

Tags: java, list, functional-programming, java-stream

I've got a `List<String>` which represents the ID's (can be duplicate), of items from another list, which is a `List<Cheat>`, where each Cheat has a String ID and a `List<Integer> RNG`. Both have accessor methods in Cheat.

I need to convert this list of ID's, into a list of RNG's for each Cheat that I have been supplied with the ID for.

For example, I could have 3 Cheats:

```
1:{ID:1, RNG:{1,2,3}}
2:{ID:2, RNG{1,2}}
3:{ID:3, RNG:{1}}
```

And a List of ID's of:

```
{3,1,1,2}.
```

I would need to end up with a final list of {1,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2}, which is the RNG's of Cheat 3, then the RNG's of cheat 1, then the RNG's of cheat 1 again, then finally the RNG's of cheat 2.

If anyone could help me out it would be appreciated. Thank you.

I've tried and failed with:

```
ImmutableList<Integer> sequenceRngs = cheatIds.stream()
                                              .map(s -> cheats.stream()
                                                                .filter(cheat -> cheat.getId().equals(s))
                                                                .findFirst()
                                                                .map(cheat -> cheat.getRng()))
                                              .flatMap(cheat -> cheat.getRng())
                                              .collect(ListUtils.toImmutableList());
```

Comment: Could you add what you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Scratch {

    static class Cheat {
        int id;
        List<Integer> rng;

        public Cheat(int id, List<Integer> rng) {
            this.id = id;
            this.rng = rng;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Cheat> allCheats = List.of(
                new Cheat(1, List.of(1,2,3)),
                new Cheat(2, List.of(1,2)),
                new Cheat(3, List.of(1))
        );

        List<Integer> result = List.of(3, 1, 1, 2).stream()
                .flatMap(id -> allCheats.stream()
                        .filter(cheat -> cheat.id == id)
                        .findFirst().orElseThrow().rng.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

The key is to use flatMap to get the result in a single - not nested - Collection in the end.

Comment: Note: This creates a stream every time for the same `id` iterating `allCheats` which can be reduced by [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59825210/17461180). e.g. for `1,1` in the input, it would iterate the `allCheats` twice.

Answer (score 1):

The lambda that you pass to `flatMap` should return a `Stream`, not a `List`. And you should handle the case where there's no such element in the stream - even if you are sure there is. Something like this should do:

```
final ImmutableList<String> sequenceRngs = cheatIds.stream().flatMap(id ->
    cheats.stream().filter(cheat -> id.equals(cheat.getId()))
        .findAny().orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new)
        .getRng().stream())
    .collect(ListUtils.toImmutableList());
```

Also, I would propose to convert the list of cheats to a map - that would simplify the code and reduce the complexity of searching from O(n) to O(1).

Answer (score 0):

You can attain that with the following steps:

1. Create a map of `cheatId` to RNG `id`s associated:

   ```
   Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = cheats.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Cheat::getId,
                   cheat -> cheat.getRng().stream().map(RNG::getId).collect(Collectors.toList())));
   ```
2. Iterate over the `cheatIds` provided as input and get the corresponding RNG ids from the map to collect as output:

   ```
   List<Integer> output = cheatIds.stream()
           .flatMap(ch -> map.get(ch).stream())
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```